# PHP - MYSQL - about calling datase and displaying on text box

Tags: php, html, sql, database

I have a table

```
EVENTCODE   EVENTNAME    VENUE   DATE   ACTION
001         Concert      Here    09/13  Reserve Now
002         Sports       Here    09/12  Reserve Now
```

I have a form pop-up when I click "Reserve Now"

```
EVENTNAME: ------ (fetch)
VENUE: --------- (fetch)
DATE: ------ (fetch)
Full Name: ---- (user input)
Contact No.: ----- (user input)
Email: ----- (user input)
[SUBMIT BUTTON]
```

Now my question is,
how do you display a certain data from the database
independently? like when I click Reserve Now on the first entry (EVENTCODE 001),
the EVENTNAME, VENUE, DATE on the first entry is reflected
on the form? and how do you fetch that "reflection" so that I can
record it as another table like transaction?

I am really getting annoyed because I cant think of a pseudocode for this or the logic for it. Please help. Thanks!

here is my code:

```
<?php

    if(mysqli_num_rows($qr)==0){
        echo ("No record fetched...<br>");
    }//end no record
    else{//there is/are record(s)
    ?>
    <div class="scroll" style="height:200px; overflow:scroll;" >
    <table width="100%"  border="1" class="altrowstable" id="alternatecolor">
      <tr align="center">
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Venue</th>
      <th>Date & Time</th>
      <th> </th>
   </tr>
<?php
    while ($record=mysqli_fetch_array($qr)){//redo to other records
?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $record['name']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $record['venue']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $record['date']; ?></td>
      <td><a href="reservemain.php" target="reserve">Reserve Now!</a></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    }//end of while
    ?>
```

Comment: thank you for the table edit <3

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to pass a unique identifier as a GET-parameter to `reservemain.php`, EVENTCODE for instance. In `reservemain.php` you then have a way to identify a particular record by the given EVENTCODE.

A practical example:

```
<td><a href="reservemain.php?event_code=<?php echo $rows['code']; ?>" target="reserve">Reserve Now!</a></td>
```

this could then be retrieved in `reservemain.php` with `$_GET['event_code']`.